# Expo Notifications - NotificationResponse not working

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I have an Expo/React Native app that receives `Firebase Messaging` notifications. Two handlers for the Firebase messages use `expo-notifications` to present a local notification with data from the remote push notification. This part works as expected.

If a user clicks on certain notifications, they need to be re-routed to specific screens. To do this, I have tried using `Notifications.getLastNotificationResponseAsync`, `Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse`, and `Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener`. `Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse` works somewhat; only on Android when the app is in the foreground, and the app crashes the first time a notification is pressed. It has to be pressed a second time, then the app opens and re-routes. `Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse` is not working on iOS, even in the foreground, and the other two did not work at all for either OS. I need this to work on both platforms and in all app states (killed, foreground, and background) without crashing.

Here is a simplified version of the current code I have for this:

```js
  const lastNotification = Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      lastNotification &&
      lastNotification.notification &&
      lastNotification.actionIdentifier ===
        ExpoNotifications.DEFAULT_ACTION_IDENTIFIER
    ) {
      const notification = lastNotification.notification;

      console.log("Notification response");

      const screen = notification.request.content.data.screen;

      navigation.navigate(screen);
    }
  }, [lastNotification]);
```